# Scala Collections: Using a value of Set find the key from a Map object.

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, set

This is a scala question.

I currently have the following two collections objects:

```
val keywordLookup = Map("a" -> "1111",
                 "b" -> "2222",
                 "c" -> "3333",
                 "d" -> "4444",
                 "e" -> "5555")

val keywordList = Set("1111", "3333")
```

The keywordLookup is a lookup object. The keywordList contains a list of values that I need to find the Ids from the keywordLookup object.

I would like the get the following result:

```
Map("a" -> "1111", "c" -> "3333")
```

Comment: Another option:
keywordLookup.filter { case (key, value) => keywordList.contains(value) }

Answer (score 2):

```
val filtered = keywordLookup.filter(kv => keywordList.contains(kv._2))
```

`filtered` is the `Map` you want as output

Answer (score 2):

```
keywordLookup.filter(x => keywordList.contains(x._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flatMap` on `find`,

```
keywordList.flatMap (k => keywordLookup.find( _._2 == k)).toMap
```